# A way to set up Ubuntu as a headless GUI?

Tags: server, ssh, remote-desktop, mate, remmina

Sorry, I know this has been endlessly re-hashed and there are a lot of articles. I did start to read that running remote desktop is kind of in a state of flux (apparently?) and that there isn't one standout contender.

Here's my goal: Box running in another room. I connect via remote desktop from my Mac using "Jump Desktop". The Ubuntu box is on all the time, no monitor or keyboard. I've actually done this with a Raspberry Pi I have for some really basic home automation, and all I have to do is put in my SSH credentials, and I'm in with a basic desktop. It's a beautiful thing.

Ubuntu hasn't been as easy. I can SSH in pretty easily, and have tried remmina. Remmina seems to work, but it requires login at the computer itself (as far as I can tell) and also sends the screen over as-is. It also doesn't seem to start after reboot. I also tried using MATE, and that would only work using the old Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection, and then it was pretty basic. I'll be running some computationally-intensive scripts with Anaconda, so I'm not sure some of that will work with MATE.

Sorry for the really dumb question. I tried to put in a few hours and some trial and error before I hit the panic button.

Comment: What program does the raspberry pi use for it's remote desktop? Does the same one not work on Ubuntu?

Comment: https://www.maketecheasier.com/enabling-remote-desktop-access-on-raspberry-pi/

This is what I was using. It has you install xrdp, but I don't that's what you were asking. After I followed those instructions, the remote desktop started working right away.

Comment: You might try using a vnc server on Ubuntu such as TightVnc.

Comment: What do you mean, sends the screen over as-is? Isn't that the desired result?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more descriptive. By "as-is", it comes across as a mirror of whatever screen is attached to it. I tried it without the screen attached, and it didn't seem to work. I'd rather have it be a session where I can just resize the window.

Answer (score 0):

- Set the headless pc up to autologin
- Install `vino` package and set `vino-server` to autostart.
- Run `vino-preferences`, set to allow remote control, set password, etc.

[image]

- Connect from other pc using `remmina`
- Profit!

Comment: Okay, so that works, but...
I unplug the display and reboot, it doesn't log back in (can't ssh, and remote desktop fails)
I have the display connected, I can connect fine, but the size is locked. I can unplug the display, but I can't re-size it. It's stuck at a large format on my smaller screen, and gets scaled to where it's hard to read the font. I tried opening up the display prefs, but controls are grayed out. 
I could get a small monitor, connect it to the "headless" box, and have it sit there doing nothing except allowing for auto-login and setting a desired screen resolution.

Comment: So it sounds like you have a couple of problems. 1) Autologin is not working. 2) Resolution of the shared desktop.   For 1), you'll have to look around on this site. I've heard of people having autologin problems but I haven't had them myself.  For 2), there are settings in remmina on the advanced tab to mess with the screen size, but I think that's scaling, which you don't like.  As far as setting the actual display size, I use Lubuntu, so I don't know how it works in Ubuntu.

Comment: I looked at my headless setup, and I see lxrandr and arandr don't work because there is no monitor connected.  However I do get some output from `xrandr --current` showing a screen size.  I don't want to mess mine up by experimenting, but maybe you could set the resolution with `xrandr`.

Comment: Cool. I'll check it out and report back. Thanks for the ideas!